# Change the version of .NET

Tags: wpf, xaml

I use an add-on that supports version 4.5.2 of .NET but my version of .NET 4. How do I change this ? Are all versions of .NET and .NET compatible with Windows 7?

Comment: .NET 4 is no longer supported nor needed for many years now. .NET 4 is the last version supported by Windows XP, which is also not supported. Upgrade your .NET SDK version.

Comment: In any case, .NET 4.x runtime versions are binary replacements. Installing a newer version replaces the previous one. This means that unless someone works on Windows XP or never installed a newer .NET version since 2012, the .NET runtime is already at 4.5 or later